# "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I am currently trying to build a State Management Library for ReactJs. But as soon as I implement it into my React project (created with `create-react-app`), it starts dropping this error:

```
Failed to compile.

path/to/agile/dist/runtime.js 116:104
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (116:104)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       if (subscriptionContainer instanceof sub_1.CallbackContainer) subscriptionContainer.callback(); // If Component based subscription call the updateMethod which every framework has to define
|
>       if (subscriptionContainer instanceof sub_1.ComponentContainer) if (this.agileInstance.integration?.updateMethod) this.agileInstance.integration?.updateMethod(subscriptionContainer.component, Runtime.formatChangedPropKeys(subscriptionContainer));
|     }); // Log Job
|
```

If I comment out the highlighted lines of code  mentioned in the error, it jumps to another point and complains there. But it can't be a syntax error because then TypeScript would complain in the IDE, too.

**How the tool works:**
At the start you have to define a framework, in this case React. Then you can create a State and subscribe this State to a React Functional Component via a Hook.
The Hook used to bind the State to the React Component simply creates a callback which triggers a re-render (via mutating a `useReducer`) and assigns this callback to the subscribed State.

If you want to know more checkout this repo:
https://github.com/agile-ts/agile

**Dependencies:**

Third Party State Management library:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.12",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.0.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "mocha": "^8.1.1",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tsc-watch": "^4.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
```

- Node: `v14.8.0`

React Project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2",
    "agile-framework": "file:../../"
  },
```

- React: `16.13.1`
- NPM: `6.14.7`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is that you're emitting ES2020 to `dist/`. If you look at the line it's complaining about:

```
if (subscriptionContainer instanceof sub_1.ComponentContainer) if (this.agileInstance.integration?.updateMethod) this.agileInstance.integration?.updateMethod(subscriptionContainer.component, Runtime.formatChangedPropKeys(subscriptionContainer));
                                                                                              // ^^                                         // ^^
```

you can see it's using the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator in the emitted code. Consumers of your library will therefore need to have appropriate configuration to handle this kind of code. Your example consumer, the CRA app, is using Babel; although the setup *does* have the transform for optional chaining, it's only run on the source code for the React app itself, *not* its dependencies (including your library).

One option for fixing it is to emit less modern code, which will reduce the amount of configuration needed by consumers. For example, if you target ES6 using the following settings in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ES6", "DOM.Iterable", "ScriptHost", "ES2016.Array.Include"],
    // ...
}
```

the React app can at least start without you needing to change your source code.

Comment: @customcommander you probably need to eject to get to the tsconfig in CRA. Are you using the official TypeScript template? It should already be targeting older runtimes for browsers.

Comment: @customcommander that does seem to target es5, assuming you mean https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux-typescript/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L3, so it shouldn't be emitting optional chaining.

Comment: @customcommander I'm not sure how that's relevant to this, then; the configuration I show is for the OP's `tsconfig.json`, they're compiling their library from TypeScript to JavaScript for use in other people's apps, including the demo CRA one in their post. I've edited my answer to clarify this.

Comment: sounds perfect! @jonrsharpe could you please advice, if I consume some library that gives me troubles like this, how I can configure Angular 11 project to work around this issue (pdfjs-dist package)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just curious if we use babel (having preset-env with target as an old browser that only understands es6) along with the typescript compiler then the above setting in typescript compiler config need not be applied right ? As babel does the conversion to es6

Comment: @DhirenPunjabi I don't think the TypeScript compiler would ever _up_-level code for a newer target, only _down_-level for older ones, but it's probably still better to set explicitly what you want it to emit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I was mentioning about down-levelling itself i.e. if we use babel for down-levelling (to es6 from higher es version) then do we have to use the tsconfig as mentioned in your answer ?

Answer (score 43):

In case you are not the author of the library, or you don't want to change it as the accepted answer suggests, you can do as follows:

1. change browserslist as @adlerer suggests:

   ```
   "browserslist": [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
   ],
   ```

   (make sure you don't have special config for `development` in `browserslist`)
2. clear npm cache:

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
3. reinstall things like @Gel suggests:

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json && npm i
   ```

This is what helped me after hours of research and trials.

Comment: Where would one change "browserlist?"

Comment: @CalebJay In package.json

Comment: What happened with browserlist? Why do we need change value of browserlist?

Comment: In my case - as I understand it - the `browserslist` did not include legacy versions for dev environment. Plus, apparently, `browserslist` holds some config data in the global cache. So if you fail to clear the cache, you end up running a different config than you think you are. Does that explain it?

Comment: Nice, worked for me

Comment: My `browserslist` has `"browserslist": {"production": [...], "development": ["last 1 chrome version", "last 1 firefox version", "last 1 safari version" ]}` , perhaps I got to make it uniform ?

Comment: @Sumax I have the same "browserslist" as you, What did you try ? have you made it inform ?

Answer (score 10):

Though it's late but still it may help someone.
In my case, I forgot to add the

```
"jsx": "react"
```

in my tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 5):

In my case setting more conservative compilation targets in `package.json` helped to resolve this issue:

```
"browserslist": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"],
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue in this case is that the version 3.2.0 of react-leaflet doesn't work for every project (i don't really know why).
im working with react using CRA take note before doing anything
Now the solution...

1. uninstall react-leaflet
2. Go to `package.json` and paste this lines

```
"react-leaflet": ">=3.1.0 <3.2.0 || ^3.2.1",  
"@react-leaflet/core": ">=1.0.0 <1.1.0 || ^1.1.1",
```

that's the way i solved the problem.
the link to the answer in another website.
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/891/860223422

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to import dependencies from "react-leaflet" to my old project but then just after importing dependencies I faced the same issue. I solved my problem by these procedures.

In terminal:

```
rm -rf node_modules && rm -f package-lock.json
npm cache clean --force
```

I know this may sound irrelevant but in next step I updated these five dependencies in "package.json" to latest versions:

1- "@testing-library/jest-dom"

2- "@testing-library/react"

3- "@testing-library/user-event"

4- "react-scripts"

5- "web-vitals"

I guess the problem is somehow related to two last dependencies but I updated all five of them just in case.

then in terminal:

```
npm i
sudo npm update -g
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue because I should use `.tsx` file but I used `.ts`.