# Additional loader for pdfjs-dist in react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, pdfjs-dist

I have the `pdfjs-dist` dependency in my react app and it isn't working - I'm not sure what I changed to cause this. I'm running `node v14.16.1`, `npm v7.9.0`, `react 17.0.2`, `react-scripts 4.0.3`, and `pdfjs-dist 2.7.570`. I'm getting the following error message when I run `npm start`:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js 2407:53
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2407:53)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|                 intent: renderingIntent,
|                 renderInteractiveForms: renderInteractiveForms === true,
>                 annotationStorage: annotationStorage?.getAll() || null
|               });
|             }
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling relevant packages, as well as `npm update`, `npm audit`, and so forth. I also tried adding the `worker-loader` npm package but it's already a peer dependency on pdfjs-dist so it made no difference. My partner on this project has the same repo and he has no issues, so I'm sure it's something on my end. I believe it has to do with support for optional chaining, but not sure how to proceed.
Thanks!

Comment: i have the same issue. i also updated worker-loader and babel-loader, but it did nothing. however, using --> const pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'] instead of const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js') works fine, but obviously linking to an online repository isnt the goal

Answer (score 6):

I just stumbled upon the same issue. What I did was to revert `pdfjs-dist` to an earlier version (2.9.359 back to 2.6.347 in my case). It all works fine now, hope it helps someone.

A possible explanation from a similar case could be found in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423384/you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this served a long day at work.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. but it not a solution if project is dependent on the API included in newer version only.

Comment: never downgrade pdf libs - older versions of a pdf lib means many pdfs won't render properly

Answer (score 2):

This helped me,

You need to import this lib asynchronously

```
let pdfjs;

(async function () { 
 pdfjs = await import("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"); 
 const pdfjsWorker = await import("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry");
  pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker; 
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

try to include the package in babel-loader rule

```
  {
    test: /\.[tj]sx?$/i,
    include: [
      /\/node_modules\/pdfjs-dist/,`enter code here`
      /\/src/,
    ],
    loader: 'babel-loader',`enter code here`
    options: {},
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need to downgrade the package version to

> **("pdfjs-dist": "2.5.207")**

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have incorrect version of webpack. Try to use es5 build
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/12905