# Erorr with nuxt-i18n

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

**Hello Stack Overflow community. I ran into a problem when starting a project on nuxt. FATAL Nuxt build error. At the moment I am not very strong in programming and errors related to routing on the server, could you help me with this problem?**

This is the body of the error that Nuxt throws.

```
ERROR in ./.nuxt/nuxt-i18n/plugin.routing.js 222:47
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (222:47)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       localeLocation: this.localeLocation,
|       // @ts-ignore
>       req: process.server ? this.$root.context?.req || this.$ssrContext?.req : null,
|       route: this.$route,
|       router: this.$router,
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js 17:0-84 259:13-47 260:10-44
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
```

It also tells me how I understood in which packages the error occurred.

```
 FATAL  Nuxt build error                                                                                                                                                                  

  at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:2127:21)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async WebpackBundler.build (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:2076:5)
  at async Builder.build (node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:327:5)
  at async Object.run (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-build.js:110:7)
  at async NuxtCommand.run (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-index.js:413:7)
```

I really dont anderstand what i need to do. I try delete .nuxt, or delete file in node_module, but it doesnt help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423384/you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same issue as the one described here:

- ["You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423384/you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders)

Take a look at your Babel configuration, and make sure you have the proper loaders before running the build again.