# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. nodejs v12 m1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, babel-loader

```
./node_modules/html-to-react/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/esm/index.js 67:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (67:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   return getFeed(parseDOM(feed, options));
| }
> export * as DomUtils from "domutils"; // Old name for DomHandler
| 
| export { DomHandler as DefaultHandler };
```

1. nodejs v12
2. use mac m1

My project did not have any errors before, but now when I run `npm start` I get this error. I can't find any answer on StackOverflow that solves my problem.

Comment: Refer.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423384/you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders

Comment: my nodejs version is 12

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/umijs/umi/issues/8109).

I had the same issue after updating from 1.0.0-rc.3 to 1.0.0-rc.12.

Reverting back to rc.3 fixed the issue:

```
npm i cheerio@1.0.0-rc.3
```