# Creating an optimized production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (256:123)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |  *     not null.
  |  */

> var gen_bitlen = function gen_bitlen(s, desc) /*    deflate_state *s;*/ /*    tree_desc *desc;    /* the tree descriptor */*/{
> |   var tree = desc.dyn_tree;
> |   var max_code = desc.max_code;

Comment: An error message alone is not enough context to understand what you're trying to do, or to debug the problem.

Comment: It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423384/you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders