# group array of object with common ids and concatenate their other properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I am trying to achieve a pretty complex iteration but havent been successful so far using reduce. Here is a small example of it

The input is as follows

```
let input = {
    "data": [
        {
            "state": "CA",
            "city": [ "Mountain View"],
            "metadata": { "id": 15 },
        },
        {
            "state": "TX",
            "city": [ "Austin" ],
            "metadata": { "id": 15 },
        },
        {
            "state": "AZ",
            "city": [ "Flagstaff" ],
            "metadata": { "id": 10 },
        },
    ],
}
```

As you can clearly see, the `id` is repeated twice in 2 objects. i want to concatenate these two objects into one when id is same. so if there are 3 objects with same id, i want to concatenate 3 objects as one. Apart from this, i also want to concatenate the `state` an `city` property when the id is matched.

So my final output should look like this

```
let result = {
    "data": [
        {
            "state": ["CA", "TX"],
            "city": ["Mountain View", "Austin"],
            "metadata": { "id": 15 },
        },
        {
            "state": "AZ",
            "city": [ "Flagstaff" ],
            "metadata": { "id": 10 },
        },
    ],
}
```

can someone please let me know how to precisely achieve this. Here is how i have tried using reduce but i could not get the expected end result.

```
let result = Object.values(input?.data?.reduce((acc, {state, city, metadata}) => {
    if (!acc[metadata?.id]) {
        acc[metadata?.id] = { id };
    }
    acc[metadata?.id].state = acc[metadata?.id].state.concat(state);
    acc[metadata?.id].city = acc[metadata?.id].city.concat(city);
    return acc;
}, {}));
```

Comment: Are you certain that's the ideal final output? I'm asking as having the `state` as *either* a string OR an array seems less than ideal

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to the solution. In order to exactly match your output, the state is kept as a string unless there are multiple states, in which case the property is converted from a string to an array.

```js
const input = {"data":[{"state":"CA","city":["Mountain View"],"metadata":{"id":15}},{"state":"TX","city":["Austin"],"metadata":{"id":15}},{"state":"AZ","city":["Flagstaff"],"metadata":{"id":10}}]}

const output = {
  data: Object.values(input.data.reduce((a, {state, city, metadata:{id}}) => {
    let o = a[id] ??= {state, city:[], metadata:{id}}
    o.city.push(...city)
    if(Array.isArray(o.state)) o.state.push(state)
    else if (state!==o.state) o.state = [o.state, state]
    return a
  }, {}))
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: hi @Andrew Parks- i get an error message "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders." Is there a simpler way to do this

Comment: @ArenTrot that looks like some kind of ReactJS configuration error, that's not my area of expertise. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423384/you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle-the-result-of-these-loaders

Comment: i can understand, but i was asking if there was an another way of implementing that doesnot result in the error. btw i got the solution from a different post

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#findIndex` to check the existence of the current `id` as follows:

```js
const input = {"data":[{"state":"CA","city":["Mountain View"],"metadata":{"id":15}},{"state":"TX","city":["Austin"],"metadata":{"id":15}},{"state":"AZ","city":["Flagstaff"],"metadata":{"id":10}}]}

const output = {
    data: input.data.reduce( (acc, {state,city,metadata:{id}}) => {
        const I = acc.findIndex( ({metadata:{id:ID}}) => ID === id ); 
        if( I > -1 ) {
            acc[I] = {
                state: typeof state === 'string' ? [...acc[I].state, state] : [...acc[I].state, ...state],
                city: [...acc[I].city, ...city],
                metadata: { id }
            }
        } else {
            acc.push({
                state: [state],
                city,
                metadata: {id}
            });
        }
        return acc;
    }, [])
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29K3j.png)

this is solution

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead, type (and format) the text

Comment: okay i will definitely look after it

Comment: Hi Jigar- please edit this so all the negative votes would go away