Running into webpack error build time using vaadin 14
My problem is the following.
I am trying to integrate a javascript library into vaadin 14 project (gridstackjs).
@NpmPackage(value = "gridstack", version = "10.1.2")
@JsModule("./index.js")
@CssImport("./style.css")
public class GridStack extends Div {
...
}

This is my java class responsible for importing the js library into the node modules.
Here is the simple code in my index.js
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css';
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack-extra.min.css';
import { GridStack } from 'gridstack';

window.initGridStack = (jsonOpts, element) => {
    const opts = JSON.parse(jsonOpts);
    const grid = GridStack.init({...opts, column: 12}, element);
}

While running a maven build, I stumble upon webpack error stating the following:
ERROR in ../node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.js?babel-target=es6 184:29
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (184:29)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       opts._alwaysShowResizeHandle = opts.alwaysShowResizeHandle;
|     }
>     var bk = opts.columnOpts?.breakpoints;
|     // LEGACY: oneColumnMode stuff changed in v10.x - check if user explicitly set something to convert over
|     var oldOpts = opts;
 @ ../node_modules/@vaadin/flow-frontend?babel-target=es6 3:0-38 6:13-22

Which is basically telling me that I need a specific loader in Webpack, that can handle this optional parameter
(opts.columnOpts?.brakepoints)
Is it possible to somehow add a loader to the Webpack that can resolve this issue ?
Currently I am using version of vaadin - 14.11.5 (vaadin flow)
P.s. I tried with vaadin 24.3.3 and the problem seems to disappear, but vaadin 24 is using Vite insteaad of Webpack and I can't really use 24 for now

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63423634/3608089

Vaadin 14 uses webpack 4.x which does not support optional chaining (?.).
Your best bet would be to upgrade to Vaadin 23, which is mostly compatible with Vaadin 14, but supports Vite which deals with all the latest frontend features.
Otherwise you might be able to use an older version of gridstack that does not use optional chaining
